# year on year year to date percentage change

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the year on year year to date change.
I have wrote something that "works", but I don't think it's good as I see it breaking if I have missing data.

any one could please advise if there is a more elegant and or reliable way to achieve that?

just to be clear:
let's say I have Jan 2018 = 10, and Feb 2018 = 30, then Feb 2018 year to date = 10 + 30 = 40
then Jan 2017 = 5, and Feb 2017 = 15, then Feb 2017 year to date = 5 + 15 = 20

so I would like Jan 2018 yoy acc change = 10 / 5 - 1 = 100% and Feb 2018 yoy acc change = 40 / 20 - 1 = 100%

here is a code sample with my try.
Any feedback most appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["YEAR", "MONTH", "VALUE"], dtype= np.float64)
i = 0


for year in range(2014, 2018, 1):
    for month in range(1, 13, 1):
        i += 1
        #print ('year ' + str(year) + ' month ' + str(month))
        df1.at[i - 1, 'YEAR'] = year
        df1.at[i - 1, 'MONTH'] = month
        df1.at[i - 1, 'VALUE'] = i

df1.at[48, 'YEAR'] = 2018
df1.at[48, 'MONTH'] = 1
df1.at[48, 'VALUE'] = 10
df1.at[49, 'YEAR'] = 2018
df1.at[49, 'MONTH'] = 2
df1.at[49, 'VALUE'] = 34
df1.at[50, 'YEAR'] = 2013
df1.at[50, 'MONTH'] = 12
df1.at[50, 'VALUE'] = 25



yearlist = df1['YEAR'].unique()

df1.sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'MONTH'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)

for year in yearlist:
    df1.loc[df1['YEAR'] == year, 'ACC'] = df1[df1['YEAR'] == year]['VALUE'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=12).sum()


df1.sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'MONTH'], ascending=[False, False], inplace=True) 
df1['CHANGE'] = df1['ACC'] / df1['ACC'].shift(-12) - 1 
df1.sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'MONTH'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU everything until `df1.sortvalues...` is preparing the data, but at least the for loop could be replaced by

```
df1['ACC'] = df1.groupby('YEAR').cumsum().VALUE
```

The calculation of `df['CHANGE']` is not clear for me, but if you want to divide the current value by the one of last year and decrement by one afterwards you're already ok...